# Is it possible to open multiple instances of Software Center?

Tags: software-center

I was wondering why I can't open more than one instance of Ubuntu Software Center?

Is there any specific reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be minimum useless since when you are installing software using the Ubuntu Software Center the system locks apt so that there are no 2 applications trying to alter files at the same time.

ie: You cant do `sudo apt-get update` (or use it for something similar) when you are installing software in the USC, the other way around is also true.